# How to use Jdbc FastExport to transfer data from teradata to Mariadb

Tags: jdbc, mariadb, teradata, fastexport

I have a big table in teradata with around 10 million rows. Need to migrate this table from teradata to mariadb on a daily basis. I read about fast export. Can it be use here programatically in java application in this case.

Comment: See the [Teradata JDBC Driver Reference](https://teradata-docs.s3.amazonaws.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/frameset.html) for details

Comment: Is there a way to "replicate" the data?